# tslint error :expected an assignment or function call

Tags: typescript

With the code

```
if (lstChildItem.cashDrawer == lstCshItems) {
  if (parseFloat(lstChildItem.currentBalance) != 0) {
    brName.indexOf(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)[0].value) === -1 
      ? brName.push(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)[0].value) 
      : '';
    trace[0].currBlnc.push(lstChildItem.currentBalance);
    currBalance = currBalance + parseFloat(lstChildItem.currentBalance);
    trace[0].frmName.push(this.formatCur(lstChildItem.currentBalance));
    trace[0].frmCurrBlnc.push(this.formatValue(lstChildItem.currentBalance));
  }
}
```

Getting the error:

```
tslint error :[438, 29]: expected an assignment or function call
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a TypeScript error, it's a tslint error (obviously? :D).

```
brName.indexOf(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)[0].value) === -1 
      ? brName.push(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)[0].value) 
      : '';
```

is a "no-op" - you can either [disable that rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-expression/) or change it to

```
if (brName.indexOf(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)[0].value) === -1) {
  brName.push(this.commonService.getBoroughs(lstItem.borough)
}
```